# Linux: manually reduce heap size

Tags: linux, memory

I'm trying to simulate memory exaustion. So here is what I'm thinking:

1. turn off over commiting.
2. reduce the available heap so that the memory exaustion can happen quicker.
3. Run the program under test.

My question is w.r.t 2: is there a trick that reduce the heap size that kernel will allocate? I can probably write another program that allocates a large amount of RAM but there might be a smarter way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove the maximum process memory size using the `ulimit` system call. The command is available from the shell. The option in question is the `-v` (max memory size), so for example to limit the process to a maximum of 2GB you would do:

```
ulimit -v 2097152
```

Then you launch the process from that shell.

If you use the `-H` option to ulimit, then it sets a hard limit which cannot be increased once it's set (root can increase the limit).

If you want control from a program, you can use the `setrlimit` system call, in a manner like:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

struct rlimit the_limit = { 2097152 * 1024, RLIM_INFINITY };
if (-1 == setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &the_limit)) {
  perror("setrlimit failed");
}
```

This sets the soft limit to `2GB`, you can set the hard limit by changing the `RLIM_INFINITY` value. Please note, you can only increase the hard limit if you're root.

This limit applies to the total amount of memory that can be used for the process, not just the memory that is usable as the heap.

The heap memory can be limited using the `-d` option. The equivalent name for the `setrlimit` call is `RLIMIT_DATA`. This limit applies to memory allocations only - e.g. malloc, mmap, static data.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `ulimit -d` you can limit the data segment size, which is used for heap allocation (as well as global/static variables).

Answer (score 0):

To simulate memory exhaustion, you can use also use mmap to map large memory segments and make sure that you "lock" them in memory. See the mmap man page on how to lock pages in memory. That way these will not get swapped, and the available memory will be reduced.

You may want to request several small sized segments (e.g. 256KB) if request for large contigious mmap segments fail. Moreoever if you want to go all the way, you may need to make your mmap process immune to the Linux "OOM killer" (by setting the OOM prio to -17). Else, when Linux sees that the system is running too low on free memory, it could select and kill your process which is calling the mmaps, in an attempt to free up memory.